# Get selected text from Textbox adjacent to a selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table containing a checkbox , some text and a select box. The user will select a checkbox and then select a value in select box. I'm trying to find out if the user has selected a value in the select box corresponding to the checked checkboxes.

Following is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  $("#submit").click(function() {

    $(".cb:checked").each(function() {
      var cb = $(this);
      console.log(cb.find('select option:selected').text());
      if (cb.find('select option:selected').text() == "-") {
        cb.find('select').css("border-color", "red");
      }
    })
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="submit">
  Save
</button>
```

The selected text value always seems to be empty. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `closest()` to get to the `tr` parent tag and then applied `find` to get to corresponding checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  $("#submit").click(function(e) {

    $(".cb:checked").each(function() {
      var cb = $(this);
      console.log(cb.closest('tr').find('select option:selected').text());
      if (cb.closest('tr').find('select option:selected').text() == "-") {
        cb.closest('tr').find('select').css("border-color", "red");
      }
    })
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="cb" type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option>-</option>
        <option>abc</option>
        <option>def</option>
        <option>ghi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="submit">
  Save
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.find()` with each checkbox, which searches descendant elements, but your select boxes aren't descendants of the checkboxes.

You could combine `.closest()` with `.find()` in order to target the selected option which corresponds to the current checkbox:

`$(this).closest('tr').find('option').filter(':selected');`

Answer (score 1):

Simply change your script code to

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  $("#submit").click(function() {

    $(".cb:checked").each(function() {
      var cb = $(this).parent().parent();
      console.log(cb.find('select option:selected').text());
      if (cb.find('select option:selected').text() == "-") {
        cb.find('select').css("border-color", "red");
      }
   else
    cb.find('select').css("border-color", "");
    })
  });


});
```